# Refresh panel in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on some project ... and when I add a user there is an information about hobby with the advantages of support -add more- hobby to the same person .

I'm thinking about divided my info into several user control and locate these user control dynamically inside the panel .

and when press the -add more- link it's build a new controls (label , textbox ...) and resize the user control containing them .

it's work but the problem is when I press -add more- the user control containing it resize well . but the panel did not build again so the user control get above other user controls without rearrange .

this is simple code of user control with add more :

```
public partial class UserControl2 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UserControl2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Size = new Size(this.Size.Width , sss.Size.Height * 3);
    }

    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Size = new Size(this.Size.Width, sss.Size.Height * 6);

    }
}
```

and the panel code is to locate when press button1 :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl1 x1 = new UserControl1();
    UserControl2 x2 = new UserControl2();
    UserControl3 x3 = new UserControl3();

    x1.Location = new Point(panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X , panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
    x2.Location = new Point(panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X , panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y + x1.Size.Height);
    x3.Location = new Point(panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X, panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y + x1.Size.Height + x2.Size.Height);

    panel1.Controls.Add(x1);
    panel1.Controls.Add(x2);
    panel1.Controls.Add(x3);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't increase the size of a control without it overlapping if you aren't anchoring the controls and increasing the size of the window.

While the form designer may look like it flows nicely, everything is created with fixed locations and sizes.  If you start increasing the size of a control without taking the other controls into account, it will be drawn over them.

You should look into either anchoring your controls and increasing the window size, within reason, or instead of changing the underlying size, add the controls inside the panel and the needed location and enable auto scrolling for the panel.

This is example code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!panel1.AutoScroll) panel1.AutoScroll = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Textbox txt = new TextBox() { Location = new Point(3, (panel1.Controls.Count * 25) + 3 };

        panel1.Controls.Add(txt);
    }
}
```

Each time you click the button it will add 3 new textbox to the panel.  You can use a similar pattern to this to accomplish what you are looking for with your own control.  It also makes sure the panel can scroll so the users can go down the list without resizing the panel or the main form.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new in c# ... so I did not understand aynyhing :D ... could you plz give me a code or command ?

Comment: I've updated the code to include a code example.  You can substitute your control in for the Textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

check out this [link:](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSCNVqVTlQ4)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
panel1.Controls.Clear();


//Then add your existing code below
serControl1 x1 = new UserControl1();
    UserControl2 x2 = new UserControl2();
    UserControl3 x3 = new UserControl3();

    x1.Location = new Point(panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X , panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
    x2.Location = new Point(panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X , panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y + x1.Size.Height);
    x3.Location = new Point(panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X, panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y + x1.Size.Height + x2.Size.Height);

    panel1.Controls.Add(x1);
    panel1.Controls.Add(x2);
    panel1.Controls.Add(x3);
}
```

Comment: I try it Tacit but the problem it's to lose the information about the textbox

Comment: Another way of doing it could be by saving the data to an xml file before u clear it then loading it again when controls are re-displayed o refreshed